# "Models aren't loaded yet" error while populating in Django 1.8 or later

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am using this code to populate my database:

```
import os
def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python')

    add_page(cat=python_cat, 
    title="Official Python Tutorial",
    url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
    url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="Learn Python in 10 minutes",
    url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat(name="Django")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Official Django Tutorial",
    url="http://djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Django Rocks",
    url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="How to Tango with Django",
    url="htttp://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat(name="Other Frameworks")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat, 
    title="Bottle",
    url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat, 
    title="Flask",
    url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user. 
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Rango population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'p.settings')
    from rango.models import Category, Page
    populate()
```

On running

```
python c:\python27\p\populate_rango.py
```

It gives the error:

```
Staring Rango population script...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\p\populate_rango.py", line 59, in <module>
populate()
File "c:\python27\p\populate_rango.py", line 4, in populate
python_cat = add_cat('Python')
File "c:\python27\p\populate_rango.py", line 52, in add_cat
c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", li
manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line
et_or_create
return self.get(**lookup), False
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line
clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line
ilter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line
filter_or_exclude
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
in add_q
clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
in _add_q
current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
in build_filter
lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
in solve_lookup_type
_, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, se
a())
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
in names_to_path
field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", li
get_field_by_name
cache = self.init_name_map()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", li
init_name_map
for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", li
get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", li
_fill_related_many_to_many_cache
for klass in self.apps.get_models():
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\lru_cache.py", line
rapper
result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 1
_models
*self.check_models_ready()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 1
ck_models_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.*
```

Rest of my files are ok but getting this error. I am following the tutorial from *Tango with Django* book but as the book refers to Django 1.5.4 and i am using Django 1.8, so can anyone help me here?

Comment: There's no reason to be using "Django 1.8". 1.7 isn't even out yet. You should be using the stable version, 1.6, or *possibly* the 1.7 release candidate.

Comment: I had this problem with Django 1.7 final.  The accepted answer fixed it.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I had the same exception with Django 1.7rc2. The solution was to add these lines at the beginning of my program:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Update: [This is now documented for Django 1.8.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

Comment: And if you're getting this error after executing `python manage.py` from Django, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25537905/540717

Comment: even though another model already worked in that package but later i import another model suddenly happened with loaded yet. Your answer solved .. thanks ..

Comment: Very useful with `unittest` and a run.py script, too! (Possibly after setting PYTHONPATH.)

Comment: Add it after the environment variable for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set. Else it will generate improperly configured errors.

Comment: Django documentation for setup() at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Answer (score 5):

We were getting this error. Our project started with Django 1.4, we went to 1.5 and then to 1.7. Our wsgi.py looked like this:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

When I updated to the 1.7 style WSGI handler:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Everything works now.

Comment: worked for me when I upgraded to django 1.8. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

well for django 1.9.x :

populate_rango.py:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tango_with_django_project.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()

def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python')

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
         title="Official Python Tutorial",
         url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat("Django")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",
        url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    #Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print ("- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p)))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Starting Rango population script...")
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django_project.settings')
    from rango.models import Category, Page
    populate()
```