# Django 1.7 throws django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

This is the traceback on my windows system.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AMD\workspace\steelrumors\manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "D:\AMD\Django\django-django-4c85a0d\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\AMD\Django\django-django-4c85a0d\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "D:\AMD\Django\django-django-4c85a0d\django\apps\config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\models.py", line 15, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "D:\AMD\Django\django-django-4c85a0d\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 135, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "D:\AMD\Django\django-django-4c85a0d\django\apps\registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "D:\AMD\Django\django-django-4c85a0d\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

And my manage.py looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import django

if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "steelrumors.settings")
    django.setup()
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I get this error when i am trying to use [registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) app in Django 1.7

Comment: You have a directory called `django-django-4c85a0d`; `4c85a0d` happens to be a (non-stable) Django commit hash. I don't believe you're actually using Django 1.7 (c.f. my answer)

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: This could also related to `venv`. Recreating the venv directory fixed it for me.

```
mv venv venv_old
virtualenv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I also meet some error like this when i add LOGGING in settings.py on my mac,this because i create a log file on /var/log/xx/debug.log and don't have the permission,so i use sudo to runserver,and everthing is fine.May help some gays

Comment: I saw this error when running `docker-compose exec ...`.  The issue was that I wasn't passing required environment variables to the command [docker-compose exec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is what solved it for us and [these folks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26636758/48735):

Our project started with Django 1.4, we went to 1.5 and then to 1.7. Our wsgi.py looked like this:

```
import os

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

When I updated to the 1.7 style WSGI handler:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Everything works now.

Comment: I don't agree with the edit from @wim, not because I think we should leave the unnecessary import, but because I was giving an example of what the autogenerated wsgi.py looked like before, and what it looked like after I had copied the differences from the 1.7 autogenerated wsgi.py.

Comment: The autogenerated `wsgi.py` file never has an `import sys` in it.  Not in 1.4, not in 1.5, and not in 1.7.  If you had it in there, it was added manually by someone - it is not added by django-admin startproject.

Comment: Good to know, my mistake (and poor memory). It had been a while since I made this but I was pretty sure that at the time I was trying to document the built in behavior.

Answer (score 239):

Running these commands solved my problem (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25244833/977116)):

```
import django
django.setup()
```

However I'm not sure why I need this. Comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, just parroting what I've read on the django 1.7 release notes about breaking changes.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-7.  Basically, Django has a new way to load installed app.  If you load Django from a Python script (like I was in my custom unit tests), some initialization needs to be done before proceeding and calling setup() is how to do it.  Aside from that, kudos to the team, my 1.6.2 to 1.7.1 upgrade seems to an hour's worth of real work.

Comment: Where do I run the above command? I add it to a .py file or what?

Comment: You should run this in the same context that the error occurs

Comment: this has enough upvotes to merit being marked the correct answer

Comment: This also solved a problem I had in a command-line update script that broke in the move to 1.7.

Comment: If you're building a standalone, you need the django.setup() call: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage The other workarounds (get_wsgi_application(), etc.) call django.setup() or something similar in the background.

Comment: I'm upgrading from 1.4, and this solution did not work while the accepted answer did. Just adding signal for others.

Answer (score 58):

The issue is in your registration app. It seems django-registration calls `get_user_module()` in `models.py` at a module level (when models are still being loaded by the application registration process). This will no longer work:

```
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I'd change this models file to only call `get_user_model()` inside methods (and not at module level) and in FKs use something like:

```
user = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

BTW, the call to `django.setup()` shouldn't be required in your `manage.py` file, it's called for you in `execute_from_command_line`. ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L354))

Comment: putting it inside ```if __name__ == '__main__':``` works for me but I don't know if it's a good solution.

Comment: @Neutralizer Not sure how are you doing that, but that shouldn't work since django is importing this module. Probably you're avoiding the circular dep by not importing the User model at all.

Comment: I mean put those lines inside name check. It might be skipping the execution. I have not made enough tests.

Answer (score 19):

Just encountered the same issue. The problem is because of `django-registration` incompatible with django 1.7 user model.

A simple fix is to change these lines of code, at your installed `django-registration` module::

```
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to::

```
from django.conf import settings
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
except ImportError:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Mine is at `.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py` (virtualenv)

Comment: You can use django-registration-redux instead. It's updated and maintained fork: https://github.com/macropin/django-registration

Comment: [`django-registration-redux`](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) fixed the issue for me (I had exactly the same stack as the OP)

Comment: In case anyone was struggling with this on Django 1.8, it also applies there as well.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me for Django 1.9 . The Python script to execute was in the root of the Django project.

```
    import django 
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PROJECT_NAME.settings")
    django.setup()
    from APP_NAME.models import *
```

Set PROJECT_NAME and APP_NAME to yours

Comment: It works for me. but I don't know why we should run this code as we already mentioned these in our wsgi file.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is that you have a duplicate entry in INSTALLED_APPS. That threw this error for two different apps I tested. Apparently it's not something Django checks for, but then who's silly enough to put the same app in the list twice. Me, that's who.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a Python virtual environment that you need to enter before you run manage.py?

I ran into this error myself, and that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm damn sure this is isn't late. If you are using `Django 4` and `.env` file for your settings, you are going to encounter this error if you define a value in settings.py while that value does not exist in `.env` file:

See following scenario:

I had PLAID_KEY in my `settings.py` as follows

```
PLAID_KEY=env('PLAID_KEY')
```

However, PLAID_KEY did not exist in my .env file, adding it fixed it.

Comment: I also had this issue. Djoser SIGNING_KEY was not available

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when I use djangocms and added a plugin (in my case: djangocms-cascade). Of course I had to add the plugin to the INSTALLED_APPS. But the order is here important.

To place 'cmsplugin_cascade' **before** 'cms' solved the issue.

Comment: order did matter: `cms, mptt, menus, sekizai, filer, easy_thumbnails`

Answer (score 2):

install django-registration-redux==1.1 instead django-registration, if you using django 1.7

Answer (score 0):

`./manage.py migrate`

This solved my issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24014876)

Comment: @GeorgeZ. It looks like an attempt to answer the question, and apparently solved the problem when this poster ran into it - even if you think it's wrong or should be elaborated more, a genuine attempt to answer the question shouldn't be deleted from review

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in a context of creating ForeignKey relations between models. Example below raises `AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet` error.

```py
from my_app.models import Workspace

workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace)
```

Then please try to reffer to a model as a string.

```py
from my_app.models import Workspace

# One of these two lines might fix the problem.
workspace = models.ForeignKey('Workspace')
workspace = models.ForeignKey('my_app.Workspace')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `manage.py` is "wrong"; I don't know where you got it from, but that's not a 1.7 `manage.py` - were you using some funky pre-release build or something?

Reset your `manage.py` to the conventional, as below, and things Should Just Work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I have a manage.py like that one and I still have this problem

Answer (score -1):

My Problem was from **init**.py . i made an app and wanted to do this :

```py
from MY_APP import myfunc
```

instead of :

```py
from MY_APP.views import myfunc
```

when i rolled back my changes to these parts . everything worked just fine.