# AppRegistryNotReady error with django 1.7 and custom User

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I am creating a custom django user and I get the following error when trying to use it. The error I get is the following

```
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

My model

```
class MyCustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Username must be defined for users")

        if not kwargs.get('email'):
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid email")

        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email), **kwargs)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(username, email,  password, **kwargs)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()


class MyCustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Email Address'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_("Ημ. Γεννήσεως"))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_("Όνομα"))
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_("Επίθετο"))
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="friends")

    objects = MyCustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Χρήστης')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Χρήστες')
```

I have also setup settings file to include my new custom user model.

(inside settings.py)

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyCustomUserModel'
```

When logging in the shell trying to use my new user type like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
user = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

i get the error above. Is there something wrong with Django 1.7

P.S: I used makemigrations and migrate to make models and I am behind a virtualenv.

Comment: How do you start the shell? Through manage.py?

Comment: @Apostolos Did you do, `import django` and `django.setup()`?

Comment: the documentation says: 

    Another common culprit is django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). Use the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting to reference the User model at import time.

Comment: Please check if any of these answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25537905/1903116), helps you.

Comment: Where should I import django.setup. I am running django shell which imports all these automatically

Comment: @GabrielAmram  I am using the AUTH_USER_MODEL whenever referencing the custom user model.

Comment: The issue seems to be when I'm running manage shell from inside pycharm

Answer (score 2):

Starting in django 1.7 you can't use get_user_model in your models.py files or you'll run into this problem. The details/reason can be seen in [referencing the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

To fix this problem, in your models.py files instead of referencing the custom user model with get_user_model, you need to import the name from settings.

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

When you fix the problem, it will fix your app as well as your shell.

Comment: I am using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL on all of my references to my custom user model. My problem is that it works from my linux terminal but not from my pycharm shell.

Answer (score 0):

This post has been here for some time, I have come across this same problem today (using Django shell) and would like to share a quick workaround by writing a custom `get_user_model()` using `import_module`.

under one of your `models.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from importlib import import_module

USER_MODEL = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.rsplit('.', 1)

def get_user_model():
    models = getattr(import_module(USER_MODEL[0]), 'models')
    return getattr(models, USER_MODEL[1])
```

This works in my local machine (Mac) under Django shell, and I hope this will also work under PyCharm shell.