# Django hung on upgrade 1.4 to 1.8

Tags: django, upgrade

I'm upgrading a Django 1.4.12 app to Django 1.8.2

Running

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

Or any other `manage.py` command hangs with no error.

Other things I tried:

```
--verbosity 3
-Wall
```

None of which gives me any feebdack and all of which hang (`-Wall` prints a list of warning coming from `matplotlib`, but nothing else).

Any idea how I can start debugging this problem?

I'm using a virtualenv and Canopy python on Mac OSX.

## UPDATE

I upgraded release by release and:

- it works with 1.5, 1.6
- it stops working on 1.7 and up.

In 1.7 and up I get the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

So I add:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

in the `models.py` that raises the error.

Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: What does `python manage.py check` say? And what about starting `shell`?

Comment: Did you update in one go (1.4 to 1.8) or step by step (1.4 -> 1.5 -> ... -> 1.8)? If in one step, restore to the backup and try it from release to release. Otherwise there are too many changes between those versions to make it simple to pinpoint migration issues.

Comment: @Blackeagle52 ``check`` hangs like every other ``manage.py`` command. @sthzg Yes, I upgraded directly. I can certainly go back and do step-by-step, but since they are two LTS releases they should have a direct upgrade method.

Comment: Updated to reflect version by version upgrade

Comment: Actually there was an interesting thread regarding the LTS upgrade path lately on the group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/qCjfOu-FPxQ

Comment: You should never have to put that code in your models.py. There might be an error in your settings that causes the app registry to not be initialized. Can you open a plain python shell with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='path.to.settings'` and see if accessing any settings (specifically `INSTALLED_APPS`) raises any errors?

Comment: It doesn't seem to raise any errors. Where does that code go then? It comes straight from the release notes.

Comment: Ok, inserting those two lines just before the ``INSTALLED_APPS`` definition in settings.py solves the problem, though I'm not sure it's the right thing to do.

Comment: in case anyone with this problem gets here without having solved this already, this problem was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load