# django:django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I got stuck on a process when I wanted to deploy a django project on the server today. When I run `python manage.py runserver` on server, the terminal shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 177, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 72, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

The django version on the server is 1.8.5, and the local is 1.8.1. I doubt the version is the cause of this problem. But I also doubt the `wsgi.py` wasn't written properly, here's the `wsgi.py`:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/Users/Peterhon/Desktop/dict/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.chdir(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dict.settings")

import django
django.setup()

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here's the `manage.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dict.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.arg)
```

When I run python manage.py check on server, the output is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dict.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Could anyone give me some tips? Thanks so much.

Comment: What does your `manage.py` file look like? Have you customised it?

Comment: Also what's the output you get from the system check? `python manage.py check`

Comment: @jamesc i haven't customised the `manage.py` file. :-(

Comment: I think that this answer might give you some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load

Comment: @jamesc i have shown the output under the question, i hope you will see. :-(

Comment: Hi - I can see your manage.py file, but the output from `manage.py check` is missing / a duplicate.

Comment: `dict` is a builtin symbol in Python, I wonder if that may be related :?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This could well be an issue with your Django settings. For example, I just had specified in `LOGGING` a filename in a non-existent directory. As soon as I changed it to an existing directory, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Had a problem with mysql and when ran `python manage.py check` got Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib   but `python manage.py runserver` gives the Apps not loaded error so it looks like any issues with settings or configuration could give this error.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue today. There was an app in INSTALLED_APPS that didn't exist. Once it was removed, it resolved the exception. Apps that can't be imported for any reason will also raise an AppRegistryNotReady exception.

[Here's the bug history for this issue.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25510)

Additionally, trying to import something from the app level into the project level can cause this issue, too. For example, I'm currently working on project using Celery Beat. I tried defining task schedules at the app level as dictionaries which were then imported to the celery.py file of the project. Importing the dictionary from the app into the project caused Django to throw an AppRegistryNotReady exception. Likewise, importing items between apps can cause the exception.

Answer (score 9):

I got this error when I tried loading a Django ORM model from inside of my Celery tasks file (which is not loaded by WSGI). To fix it, I put the following initialization code at the top *above* the import for the model class.

```py
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings")
django.setup()

# Django dependencies below this line
from myapp.models import MyModel
```

Django docs recommend this unusual approach here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Comment: Solved a similar issue with a scraper using a django model, thanks for sharing your solution! :)

Answer (score 5):

`./manage.py runserver` will use your `wsgi.py` however it looks like the stack trace you've shown at the top does not include the wsgi file. Therefore the error is occurring before the wsgi file is loaded.

I'm not able to recreate your error, but since you seem to be using the new style wsgi and as you mention "the django version on the server is 1.8.5, and the local is 1.8.1", I'm wondering if there might be something wrong in your environment.

My suggested steps are:

1. Rebuild your virtualenv. Delete the env folder and install again with `pip install -r requirements.txt` or similar.
2. Check out other questions on StackOverflow - this seems to be a common issue. E.g as above: [Django 1.7 throws django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load)

Hopefully someone with more experience will be able to add suggestions. Sorry I don't have the definitive answer for you.

Comment: `raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")` it clearly sound like an other error than models not loaded yet…

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when importing a Model into apps.py

I needed this Model to use it as an argument when connecting a Signal in the `ready` method.

I solved it by importing the Model **inside** the `ready` method (in the Django docs [they also do imports inside the ready method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions))

I leave a snippet below that shows what I did

```py
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from myproject.apps.core.utils import my_receiver



class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "tracker.apps.core"

    def ready(self):
        from .models import MyModel # HERE IT IS! MOVING THE IMPORT HERE SOLVED IT

        post_save.connect(my_receiver, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: this answer slove my problem

Answer (score 0):

There can be issue in your settings.py file . Specifically INSTALLED_APPS verify if you correctly included apps and separated with "," .

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too regardless of the existing answers. I solve by do locally import in the celery function.

Comment: can you give more details, as it is hard to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the owner of the wsgi entry point that the apache calls to root:root

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same issue when i was adding an authentication backend to my settings.py PyCharm automatically imports all requirements which are used in a file so
PyCharm imported the model and this causes an app not ready error in the registry.py check_apps_ready method

so the solution that works for me is basically check imported modules and remove unnecessary module imports [the import to be removed to resolve that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm8ky.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `python 3.8` and `MacOS Ventura 13.4` this issue stemmed from `context` in used. In the beginning I used `spawn` and it gave the me the error. I changed it to `fork` and it worked.

Roughly, `spawn` creates a fresh child process that inherits the absolutely necessary resources and `Django` models is not one of those. `fork` though is identical to the parent and everything is loaded. However, fork may be unsafe e.g. it does not copy the parent process’s threads and thus deadlock may appear.