# How to run a group of celery tasks? Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, celery

For example, I have a two tasks: `a` and `b`.
I need to run them in parallel. I create a group of tasks and try run it. But I get error

**proj/app/tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def a():
    pass

@app.task
def b():
    pass
```

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Application `app` is registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` and all migration complited

**proj/proj/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**proj/proj/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))


from celery import group
from app.tasks import a, b

run_group = group(a.s(), b.s())
run_group()
```

**Traceback**

```
File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/test_projects/proj/proj/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/test_projects/proj/proj/celery.py", line 26, in <module>
    from app.tasks import a, b
File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/test_projects/proj/app/tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .models import Link, Prediction, PredictionBK
File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/test_projects/proj/app/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
```

Comment: Why do you have that `from .celery import app as celery_app` in your `__init__.py`?

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

Comment: its `app.task`, not `app.tasks`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It allows `shared_task` to detect the app that it should use.

Comment: Looks like your settings are improperly configured somehow.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186413/djangodjango-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**proj/proj/celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

**proj/proj/settings.py**

```
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
```

**proj/proj/__init__.py**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

**proj/app/tasks.py**

```
from celery import group


@app.task
def a():
    pass


@app.task
def b():
    pass


run_group = group(a.s(), b.s())
run_group()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do the following:

- reset your server
- reset your celery worker pool

If that doesn't fix the problem let me know.

Also, you don't need the `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals`.  This is only used for python2 compatibility.

### Update

I just realized that you are importing them into your celery file (not sure if you can do this).  Try deleting the task import, then try running the task in a django shell (run `./manage.py shell`).

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Added an update.  See if that works.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук I posted a related question in the comments.  Can you show your `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

Firstly you should not be importing the other tasks - that is what `app.autodiscover_tasks()` is for. Remove the line `from app.tasks import a, b`

Secondly, you should not be *calling* `run_group`. That's for when you want to run the tasks in the group.

Comment: but I want to run tasks in a group.

Comment: Yes. *Define* `run_group` there, as you are doing. But don't *call* it there. Call it when you want to run the group.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for help. At now I get error `amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.`

Comment: It’s strange. After all, I use `redis`, and the error is related to `rabbitmq`?

Answer (score -1):

#### change your `proj/proj/celery.py` to this:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

import django
django.setup()

from celery import group
from app.tasks import a, b

run_group = group(a.s(), b.s())
run_group()
```