# Delete a database row in Django SQLITE3 database

Tags: django, database, sqlite, delete-row

How do you delete a row in a Django database at the interpreter level. I'm troubleshooting a database and I would like the ability to target specific rows in a Django sqlite3 database.

Currently I can create entries in the database as follows:

```
>> Item.objects.create(text='Item A')
```

Which I can view in the database using:

```
>> for p in Item.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appName_model'):
...    print(p.text)
...
```

And I correctly get the database contents (their text fields).

Having trouble with targeting a specific row by index, text_field or by some other attribute. I am troubleshooting directly at the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Item.objects.get(text='Item A').delete()
```

EDIT:

By the way, Django has more methods for interacting with models. For example, looping over the Item objects:

```
for item in Item.objects.all():
    print item.name
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/

Comment: This works, thanks. Though I must add, I got an error of (django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet) which is solved via : [[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load  ]], by adding BEFORE the delete in the command-line python interpreter : >> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application >> application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: Great! And... You can use `python manage.py shell` to do that for you.

Comment: How would I delete the first element, second element, etc?

Comment: `Item.objects.all()[0].delete()`, `Item.objects.all()[1].delete()`, and so on.