# Why won't my task run? when I do I get a huge traceback

Tags: python, django, redis, queue, scheduled-tasks

I dont quite understand how tasks work. I ran the example from the docs on the rq site and it ran just as it was supposed to. So then I tried to use a function that I created. So i imported it like this

my task.py

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
from src.blog.my_scraps import panties

import requests

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()


panties()
```

and what I got was this

```
(practice) apples-MBP:practice ray$ python my_raddqueue.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_raddqueue.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_task import conn, is_page_ok #count_words_at_url
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/my_task.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.blog.my_scraps import panties
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Post
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/taggit/managers.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 159, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 160, in ContentType
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I am new to django and even newer to python, and I just started working with rq yesterday because I want to automate my site. I see that it says

```
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

but I'm not clear on exactly what to do. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

### EDIT

this is the function I'm trying to use

```
 def p_panties():

        def swappo():
            user_one = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" '
            user_two = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)" '
            user_thr = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" '
            user_for = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0" '

            agent_list = [user_one, user_two, user_thr, user_for]
            a = random.choice(agent_list)
            return a

        headers = {
            "user-agent": swappo(),
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "accept-charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        }

        from lxml import html
        pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
        shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})
        name = 'pan videos'

        if os.getenv('_system_name') == 'OSX':
            author = User.objects.get(id=2)
        else:
            author = User.objects.get(id=3)

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row]
            tubby = str(entries[4])
            urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tubby)
            return urls

        def embed(url):
            new_embed = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
            return new_embed

        entries = [{'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[1],
                    'text': div.h4.text,
                    'comments': div.h4.text,
                    'name': name,
                    'url': div.a.get('href'),
                    'embed': embed(youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[0]),
                    'author': author,
                    'video': True,
                    } for div in video_row][:13]

        for entry in entries:
            post = Post()
            post.title = entry['text']
            title = post.title
            if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
                post.title = entry['text']
                post.name = entry['name']
                post.url = entry['url']
                post.body = entry['comments']
                post.image_url = entry['src']
                post.video_path = entry['embed']
                post.author = entry['author']
                post.video = entry['video']
                post.status = 'draft'
                post.save()
                post.tags.add("video", "Musica")

        return entries
```

### EDIT

I tried

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=gettingstarted.settings
```

and got the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "my_raddqueue.py", line 1, in <module>
        from my_task import conn, is_page_ok #count_words_at_url
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/my_task.py", line 6, in <module>
        from src.blog.my_scraps import panties
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .models import Post
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
        from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/taggit/managers.py", line 7, in <module>
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 159, in <module>
        class ContentType(models.Model):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 160, in ContentType
        app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
        self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named 'gettingstarted'
```

mysettings are in a settings directory

```
 gettingstarted\
     __init__.py
     base.py
     local.py
     production.py
```

I also tried

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="gettingstarted.settings.base"
```

and I also tried

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="src.gettingstarted.settings.base"
```

and got got the message

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "my_raddqueue.py", line 1, in <module>
        from my_task import conn, is_page_ok #count_words_at_url
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/my_task.py", line 6, in <module>
        from src.blog.my_scraps import panties
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/my_scraps.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .models import Post
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/src/blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
        from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/taggit/managers.py", line 7, in <module>
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 159, in <module>
        class ContentType(models.Model):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
        app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
        self.check_apps_ready()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
        raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

### EDIT

this is my wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gettingstarted.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

this is a snippet of my settings/base.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # local
    'blog',

    # Third party
    'crispy_forms',
    'taggit',
    'haystack',
    'whoosh',
    'pagedown',
    'markdown_deux'
)
```

### EDIT

tried adding this to my my_task.py

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from src.gettingstarted.settings import base

settings.configure(default_settings=base, DEBUG=True)
django.setup()
```

and I'm getting a new error message

```
File "my_raddqueue.py", line 1, in <module>
        from my_task import conn, count_words_at_url, lett, p_panties # is_page_ok
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/my_task.py", line 13, in <module>
        django.setup()
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
        configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 173, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
    AttributeError: module 'src.gettingstarted.settings.base' has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'
```

### EDIT

I added

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
```

to my base.py because of this message

```
module 'src.gettingstarted.settings.base' has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'
```

then when I added that I got a new message

```
module 'src.gettingstarted.settings.base' has no attribute 'LOGGING'
```

so then I added

```
LOGGING = None
```

then I got this message

```
 No module named 'blog'
```

I'm trying another approach at this point because this is getting annoying. I think the problem is occuring because my function scrapes and and adds data to my models which I guess needs authentication.

these two imports

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from src.blog.models import Post
```

are causing the traceback message

```
        File "my_raddqueue.py", line 1, in <module>
        from my_task import conn, count_words_at_url, lett # is_page_ok
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/my_task.py", line 10, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
        class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 50, in AbstractBaseUser
        password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
        self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named 'gettingstarted'
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26089302/2808371) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings). Hopefuly this will help.

Comment: @an0o0nym Hey since you've posted your answer I have been trying what you suggested and variations of it. Take a look above at the traceback

Comment: The most common problem which can be causing that is that you might have an app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` (`settings.py`) that does not exist. So you may just want to check and update or delete if you find any incorrect apps in there. Also look for mising colons.

Comment: @an0o0nym I added a snippet of my settings. the installed apps, above.  DoYou see what might be causing this in my function? why would I have to do this extra step if my job is just essentially a function?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26215548/2808371)! [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) is some more explanation.

Comment: @an0o0nym You are giving me the tools but I do not know how to use them. A lot of these terms I am not familiar with because the tutorial doesn't mention them. Thanks for trying to help me though

Comment: @an0o0nym see above. I tried what you suggested, not sure if it's right though. I tried it with my local.py, base and production and got the new traceback stated above