# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.- django 1.11

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

After trying to implement Token Authentication using DRF, i get this error raised in my terminal. I have had seen other related [relevant questions with solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load/27426582#27426582) but none of them solved my issue.

Below is my **wsgi.py**

```
"""
WSGI config for myApp project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myApp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**stack trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/peaceApp/peace/models.py", line 28, in <module>
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 464, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 371, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 782, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 800, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1261, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1165, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1045, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1342, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 115, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "/Users/emmnock/Desktop/peaceAppProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 132, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: please add the full stacktrace and relevent section of settings

Comment: @e4c5 stacktrace updated

Comment: Your problem is in `peaceApp/peace/models.py` on 28'th line to be exact `Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`. Add `peaceApp/peace/models.py` to your question

Comment: thank you @SardorbekImomaliev

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your wsgi.py like this,

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```