# Python 2.7 django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-apps

I am new at learning Django, I am using django-1.11.4. By default I was using python 2.7. I have gone through some of the similar questions but no luck. Please suggest.

This is my Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/skum/PQP_Bridge/qspraw7_data/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from models import PqpModel
  File "C:\Users\skum\PQP_Bridge\qspraw7_data\models.py", line 14, in <module>
    class PqpModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_cassandra_engine\models\__init__.py", line 448, in __new__
    name=name
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_cassandra_engine\models\__init__.py", line 489, in _add_django_meta_and_register_model
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

These are the apps I installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_cassandra_engine',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'qspraw7_data.apps.Qspraw7DataConfig',
    'chartit',
]
```

apps.py;

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class Qspraw7DataConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'qspraw7_data'
```

Comment: Please make sure django environment activate.

Comment: What is the command you executed? Did you just do "python views.py"?

Comment: I am using pycharm. I just clicked on run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following commands

```
import django
django.setup()
```

If above not working try following changes

For django 1.7 and less version

```
import os
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

For django 1.7 WSGI file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

May this helps you

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: when i run djange.setup() in python console, i got an error. i dont understand the error.please suggest

Comment: Are you activate your django environment

Comment: Reffer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load?rq=1)

Comment: Django environment is up and running.