# Django 1.7.2 - Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following error when I try to start my local development server:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 199, in get_model
self.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

So I searched SO for an answer and came across [this relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244631/models-arent-loaded-yet-error-while-populating-in-django1-8-and-python2-7-8/25244833#25244833) that looks the best avenue for me.

The accepted answer states that:

The solution was to add these lines at the beginning of my program:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

**I have no idea how or where I should add these two lines to my code so that the lines are at the beginning of my program.** I have searched SO & Google, but could not solve this issue.

I am hoping that someone can easily explain to me **exactly where** I should add the two lines of code so that they are at the **beginning** of my program. I am really unsure where the beginning of my code / program officially is.

**EDIT**

This is the contents of my wsgi.py file:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "globalx.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27426582/2011147

Comment: What does your `wsgi.py` file look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django 1.7 throws django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537905/django-1-7-throws-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-models-arent-load)

Comment: haleyhansen - added my wsgi.py file code to the post above.

Comment: elecrometro - How is this post a duplicate of another post I have made reference to that is asking for refinement of a solution?